# How to change up button material design to 'x'

Tags: android, material-design

This print is inbox screen

[image]

How can I do this 'x' button on my action bar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the home button of Action bar, and you can customize this in style -

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: There's a way to do it to a specific activity via xml?

Comment: yes, while coming to this activity you can add specific style for this Activity in AndroidManifest. This will work.

Comment: I tried this and the button was very big and ugly... I tried  getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon) too, not enought...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this programmatically, using the line:

```
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable/icon);
```

This will let you adjust the icon depending on what you are showing.
Switch getActionBar() to getSupportActionBar() if you are using AppCompat.

Comment: @Douglas I would suggest getting icons from [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-system-icons). As per the design guidelines, for the App Bar you should choose 24dp icons.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        Drawable X = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_X);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(X);
```